# Фінансова звітність аудитована чи ауди(і)йована?

Tags: терміни, запозичені-слова, прикметники, словотворення

Ні Закон України **["Про аудит фінансової звітності та аудиторську діяльність"](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2258-19)**, ні його попередник (ЗУ "Про аудиторську діяльність") не містять дієприкметників, похідних від терміну **`аудит`**.

Смішно, але відсутній навіть сам цей іменник і в СУМ-20, і в СУМ, який містить тільки іменник **`аудитор`**, та й то далеко не зі сучасним значенням:

> **[АУДИ́ТОР](http://sum.in.ua/s/audytor)**, АВДИ́ТОР, а, чол., заст.
>
> 1. У дореформених семінаріях — учень, призначений учителем перевіряти, як вивчили урок його товариші. Перевели мене в семінарію, зачув я
>      волю. Дивлюсь, *авдиторів* немає, греки та латини валяються в нас під
>      ліжками (Нечуй-Левицький, I, 1956, 127).
> 2. дорев. Прокурор.
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 1, 1970. — Стор. 72.

Дієприкментник ***аудитований*** знаходимо в Економічному словнику: банківська справа, фондовий ринок (українсько-англійсько-російський тлумачний словник) під ред. Алексеєнко Л.М., Олексієнко В.М., Юркевич А.І. — К.: Видавничий будинок «Максимум»; Тернопіль: «Економічна думка», 2000. — 592 с.

[image]

Утім, в мережі поряд з варіантом **`аудитований`**:

> Наявність *аудитованої* публічної фінансової звітності в компанії
>   допомагає цілому колу її користувачів ефективно взаємодіяти з
>   компанією, підкріплює її статус і забезпечує високий рівень
>   корпоративного управління. Крім того, *аудитована* фінансова звітність
>   допомагає компаніям отримати доступ до ринків фінансового капіталу і
>   стимулює інвестиції, як внутрішні, так і зовнішні.

- *[Стаття "Якість аудиторських послуг: проблеми та перспективи" (О.О. Ільченко, М.В. Кузуб)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:UkDrfOjpE0cJ:nasoa.edu.ua/wp-content/uploads/periodicals/b-obl/162/05.pdf%20&cd=15&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua)*

> Однією з основних вимог, що ставляться до компанії-емітента незалежно
>   від обраного майданчика є *аудитована* фінансова звітність, складена
>   згідно вимог Міжнародних стандартів фiнансової звiтностi ( МСФЗ) за
>   1-3 останніх роки діяльності.

*[- Стаття "Оцінка можливості здійснення успішного ІРО акціонерними товариствами України в умовах євроінтеграції" (Н.О. Чех)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Vto_4Pm69e8J:khg.kname.edu.ua/index.php/khg/article/download/4734/4694/%20&cd=13&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua)*

зустрічається й **`аудийований`**:

> *Аудийований* чистий прибуток RosUkrEnergo в 2006 р. виріс на 4% у
>   порівнянні з 2005 р. - з 755,4 млн дол. до 785 млн дол., виручка
>   трейдера від експорту газу в 2006 р. склала 7 млрд 135,9 млн дол.

*[- Інтернет-ресурс РБК-Україна](https://www.rbc.ua/ukr/news/gruzooborot_odesskogo_mtp_za_9_mes_2007_g_uvelichilsya_na_10_8_do_23_8_mln_t__1191834981)*,

але, що більш дивно, частіше - **`аудійований`**:

> Найбільша нафтогазовидобувна компанія України ПАТ «Укрнафта»
>   опублікувала *аудійовану* фінансову звітність за 2016 рік, підтверджену
>   незалежним зовнішнім аудитом PWC.

*[- сайт ПАТ "Укрнафта"](https://www.ukrnafta.com/aud%D1%96jovana-f%D1%96nansova-zv%D1%96tn%D1%96st-ukrnafta-za-2016-r%D1%96k)*

> Про це йдеться в *аудійованій* консолідованій звітності НАК «Нафтогаз
>   України» за міжнародними стандартами фінансової звітності (МСФЗ),
>   обнародуваній на офіційному сайті компанії.

*[- Інформаційне агентство "Уніан"](https://www.unian.ua/society/583930-naftogaz-mae-namir-zavershiti-likvidatsiyu-dk-gaz-ukrajini.html)*,

що, на мою думку, не зовсім правильно, оскільки маємо омонім зі значенням "у форматі аудіо":

> Формат дейзі дозволяє незрячому користувачеві протягом лічених секунд
>   знайти в *аудійованій* книзі потрібний розділ, параграф, сторінку,
>   абзац, фразу.

- *[Інтернет-ресурс lviv.vgorode.ua](https://lviv.vgorode.ua/news/24/250188-yak-na-lvivschyni-stvoruivatymut-pershu-biblioteku-dlia-luidei-z-vadamy-zoru)*,

який видається логічнішим варіантом (*аудіо, аудіювання, аудійований*), аніж похідний від *аудиту*.

P.S. [Пошук Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&oq=%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.12797j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ще видає результати з **`аудований`**, логіка творення якого мені теж не зрозуміла.

**А який із наведених варіантів відповідає нормам словотворення дієприкметників в українській мові?**

Comment: Я думаю, вся справа в наявності в російській мові слів _[аудировать](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=аудировать&all=x)_, _[аудирование](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=аудирование&all=x)_, _аудированный_ (іноді вживають _ауди**ти**ровать_, _-ние_, _-нный_, але нормативними й найуживанішими є саме перші три). Близькість і вплив російської мови переважує і словотворчу логіку (аудіо → аудіювати, аудит → аудитувати), і власні словники (_[аудіювати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=188929)_ vs _[аудитувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=170924)_).

Comment: @Sasha, логіка такого словотворення в російській мові мені теж не зрозуміла, бо знову ж таки - омонімізація та сама, хоча її легко можна уникнути, не порушивши правил словотворення: ***аудіо*** - *аудійований*, *аудіювати*, ***аудит*** - *аудитований*, *аудитувати*.

Comment: Латинське _audītus_ (від якого походить наше _аудит_) походить від латинського _audiō_ (від якого походить наше _аудіо_). Щоправда зазвичай запозичені слова живуть в мові-акцепторі своїм життям (незалежним від етимології слова в мові-оригіналі), тому злиття російських _аудировать_ й _аудитировать_ це не пояснює. Мабуть, слово просто ненавмисне скоротили, і так усталилося; або ж у якійсь проміжній мові (якщо росіяни/українці запозичили ці слова не прямо з латини) поняття _аудіювати_ й _аудитувати_ були теж змішані.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Коротко:

Найкраще використовувати слово "аудитований", адже, як вже зазначалося у питанні й коментарях, воно дозволяє уникнути різночитання, а також широко вживається у науковій і офіційній літературі.

## Відносно довге інтернет-дослідження:

### 1. Аудитований.

[45 результатів](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&lr=lang_uk&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&ei=gIdYXNqRKKGLmgX8256IBQ&start=0&sa=N&filter=0&ved=0ahUKEwja0evM3aLgAhWhhaYKHfytB1E4KBDy0wMIRA&biw=1366&bih=657) ґуґла на слово "аудитований" в лапках лише українською мовою.

Перші три посилання — на російський сайт.

Далі на сайті http://cyclop.com.ua/ є "Фінансово-економічний словник" - Загородній А.Г.:

> **АУДИТОВАНИЙ** ЗВІТ - див. Звіт **аудитований**.
>
> ЗВІТ **АУДИТОВАНИЙ** - звіт підприємства, що пройшов аудиторську перевірку.

Далі [Міжнародна орґанізація з міґрації](http://iom.org.ua/ua) має форму [заявки на перекваліфікацію](http://iom.org.ua/sites/default/files/ua1-2017-523_-_dodatok_1_-_forma_zayavky_na_prekvalifikaciyu.xlsx) (обережно, завантаження Excel-файлу), де бачимо:

> **Аудитований** фінансовий звіт за 2016 фінансовий рік.

Ще одне посилання на "Річну інформацію емітента цінних паперів за 2017 рік" міжнародної будівельної компанії "konecranes":

> По шостому питанню слухали Тарасова Сергiя Олександровича та прийняли рiшення затвердити рiчний **аудитований звiт** Приватного акцiонерного товариства "Конекрейнс Україна" за 2016 рiк.

Далі та сама фірма отримала звіт від [openprocurement.org](https://public.docs.openprocurement.org/get/d77d3876925648a6bb0464d6a636581e?KeyID=52462340&Signature=9%252Be8ZSYHS50fMqLAwUyN%252BAcJ84p6%252BFwcwoL4TsKFnxp7%2FfviZ4CamR7CAU2vXkSF8QjUC0NB0jgV%2FF%2FOzJBwBA%253D%253D) (обережно, за посиланням завантаження пдф-файла):

> Затвердити річний **аудитований** звіт Приватного акціонерного товариства „Конекрейнс. Україна” за 2010 рік.

Далі йде виданий під маркою КПІ [термінолоґічний словник](http://ela.kpi.ua/bitstream/123456789/19112/1/menedzhment_yakosti.pdf) (обережно, за посиланням завантаження пдф-файла) — Шишкін В.М., Чікін С.В.:

> АУДИТОВАНИЙ – AUDITEE – Особа або організація, яка піддається аудиту

Далі: Мартинюк Н.Ю. (асистент кафедри обліку та аудиту Луцького національного технічного університету) "[ОБЛІКОВІ АСПЕКТИ АУДИТУ ЯКОСТІ](http://www.global-national.in.ua/archive/2-2014/260.pdf)" (обережно, за посиланням завантаження пдф-файла) в електронному виданні "[Глобальні та національні проблеми економіки](http://www.global-national.in.ua)":

> преамбула: назва підприємства, імена співробітників, з якими проводились бесіди, дати, програми, посилання на стандарт чи інші документи, **аудитований** (підрозділ чи відділ);

Далі ще не одне наукове видання використовує це слово: [1](http://blogs.kpi.kharkov.ua/v2/quality/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/06/Slovnyk-terminiv-ta-vyznachen-1.pdf), [2](http://old.minjust.gov.ua/file/31111), [3](http://194.44.152.155/elib/local/sk629872.pdf), [4](http://academy.gov.ua/pages/dop/136/files/da8e2d7c-7c24-4fcf-a0c7-0a95238dff06.PDF) тощо.

### 2. Аудийований.

[15 результатів](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&lr=lang_uk&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&ei=zo5YXL31EILLrgS39LGQCA&start=0&sa=N&filter=0&ved=0ahUKEwi9lKzI5KLgAhWCpYsKHTd6DII4ChDy0wMIRQ&biw=1366&bih=608) ґуґла на слово "аудийований", з них жодного наукового і декілька російських.

### 3. Аудійований.

[27 результатів](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&lr=lang_uk&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&ei=r49YXNCjFceqrgSjvbR4&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiQt9Wz5aLgAhVHlYsKHaMeDQ84FBDy0wMIYw&biw=1366&bih=608) ґуґла на це слово. З них по декілька разів повторюються новини про "аудійований прибуток аеропорту "Бориспіль"" ([1](https://www.epravda.com.ua/news/2016/07/5/598152/), [2](http://univer.ua/ua/financial-news/pributok-aeroportu-borispil-perevishiv-pivmilyarda-20160705/), [3](http://patrioty.org.ua/all/2016-07-06.html) тощо), потім про "прекрасний аудійований банк", потім декілька разів йдеться не про аудійований звіт, а про аудійований стандарт ([1](http://www.academia.edu/16703872/%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%86%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%98_%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%A6%D0%86%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%87_%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%AF%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%86_%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%A2%D0%86%D0%92_%D0%A3_%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%9A%D0%A3%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%A2%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%A3_%D0%A1%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%98%D0%A9%D0%86), [2](http://csr-ukraine.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/draft-CSR-terminology.docx), [3](http://chasopis.geci.stu.cn.ua/nomer/2016/1/seriya_1/ua/26-32.pdf) (обережно, останні два посилання - завантаження файлів) тощо), декілька посилань на "[аудійований звук](http://www.confcontact.com/2012_06_14/fl4_govtva.htm)", "[аудійований період](https://ppt-online.org/172218)", "[аудійований характер навчального середовища](http://www.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe?C21COM=2&I21DBN=ARD&P21DBN=ARD&Z21ID=&Image_file_name=DOC/2002/02somsnf.zip&IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD=1)".

Отже, маємо дуже багато різночитань, незрозуміло, де саме використовувати це слово, майже немає достатньо поважних джерел зі словосполученням "аудійований звіт" - ґуґл видає [два результати](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_uk&biw=1366&bih=608&tbs=lr%3Alang_1uk&ei=c5FYXNXgDrKFrwSi4puwCw&q=%22%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%22&oq=%22%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...88706.89212..89354...0.0..0.151.452.4j1......0....1..gws-wiz.C118WprAhGk).

## Словотворення дієприкметників в українській мові:

Дієприкметник "аудитований" твориться від доконаного дієслова ["аудитувати"](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=170949&page=83):

> АУДИТУВА́ТИ, у́ю, у́єш, недок. і док., що. Здійснювати аудит. Аудитувати приватне підприємство.

Читаємо [правило](http://webpen.com.ua/pages/Morphology_and_spelling/participle_passive_forms.html):

> Якщо **основа** дієслова в неозначеній формі **закінчується на -а**, то до неї додаємо суфікс -н(ий): обладна(ти) — обладнаний, **обговорюва(ти) — обговорюваний**, спиля(ти) — спиляний.

Тоді аудитувати - аудитований.

### Висновок:

Враховуючи вищенаведену інформацію, докладаючи до неї інформацію з самого запитання і коментарів, можемо виснувати, що найпоширеніше й найдоцільніше з трьох словосполучень - словосполучення **"аудитований звіт"**.